# How to automatically uncheck checkbox if textbox is filled

Tags: javascript, checkbox, default, textfield

I've made the checkbox to be  default check.  How can I uncheck the checkbox automatically if certain textfield is filled. I've thinking of using javascript.

---

I tried using this

```
<input type="text" name="commentID" id="commentID" onkeyup="userTyped('skipID', this)"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="skipID" value="N" id="skipID" checked="checked"  />
```

and the javascript

```
function userTyped(commen, e){
if(e.value.length > 0){
    document.getElementById(commen).checked=false;
}else{
    document.getElementById(commen).checked=true;
}}​
```

It works but how if i have 3 textfield, and  I want the checkbox to be filled only after all textfield is filled.

Comment: In addition to @JosephtheDreamer's comment, http://whathaveyoutried.com.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="someid" checked="checked"/>

<textarea onchange="if (this.value != '') document.getElementById('someid').checked = false;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Yuck... inline javascript.

Comment: @Nile LOL, yeah, I agree with you :P But it is just a little example.

Comment: @Mickle Foretic what if i have 3 different textfield.  And only after all three texfield is filled only  will the checkbox be unchecked

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(document.getElementById('yourtextBox').value!=' ')
 {
    document.getElementById('checbox').checked=false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. In this code, each time when you type a character in the textfield, the function will be called and the length of the textfield value is not zero, the checbox will be unchecked and it will be checked while you clear your textfield

```
//Function get called when you type each letter
function OnChangeTextField(){
    //getting the length of your textbox
    var myLength = $("#myTextbox").val().length;
    if(myLength > 0){
        $("#myCheckbox").attr("checked", false);
    }else{
           $("#myCheckbox").attr("checked", true);
        }

}


<input type = "text" id = "myTextbox" onkeyup= "OnChangeTextField();"/>
<input type="checkbox" id = "myCheckbox" value = "true" checked = "checked"/>
```

Comment: How if I want the checkbox to be unchecked  if lets say after  3 textfield have been checked. I tried this and it works, but lets say I want the checkbox to be automatically  unchecked only  after 3 textfield is filled.

Comment: You can use a counter variable and after leaving each text field(on blur event) check the length of the textfield and you can simply increment the counter variable, if the text field contains any values. And when the counter variable reaches 3, you can uncheck the checkbox using the code

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand what you are saying... @Anand

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#comment").on("keyup blur", function () {
    $("#box").prop("checked", this.value == "");
});
```

[EDIT: You can also use jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/YpRyx/)

Answer (score -1):

```
 $("#comment").on("keyup blur", function() {
    $("#box").prop("checked", this.value == "");
});
```

[Try jQuery, This works for me...](http://jsfiddle.net/mannielucero/SF7F7/2/)

Comment: The problem is that this does not answer the question.  The checkbox is unchecked on `focus` here which applies even if there is nothing in the checkbox as opposed to waiting for it to be filled.

Comment: Ok, I made a new solution.